# SQL Server slow query

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

i have a query that is more slow and i don't understand why. I think, there are the corrects indexes on the tables..

```
SELECT
    e.id, e.coordinate, e.lat AS latitudine, e.lon AS longitudine, e.dataora, e.indirizzo, e.dato, e.precisione_metri, e.precisione_secondi, e.precisione_invalid, e.distanza, e.velocita, es.descrizione AS evento, es.operazione, es.colore_shape, e.dato barcode, es.gestione_euristica, e.id_dispositivo  
FROM eventi_kml_polygon AS ekp
INNER JOIN eventi AS e
    ON e.id=ekp.id_evento
INNER JOIN sistema_eventi AS es
    ON es.evento=e.id_evento
INNER JOIN kml_polygon AS kp
    ON kp.id=ekp.id_kml_polygon
INNER JOIN kml AS k
    ON k.id=kp.id_kml
INNER JOIN waypoint AS w
    ON w.id_kml=k.id
INNER JOIN waypoint_periodi AS wp
    ON (wp.id_waypoint=w.id AND e.dataora BETWEEN wp.dataora_inizio AND wp.dataora_fine)
INNER JOIN modelli AS m
    ON m.id=wp.id_modello
WHERE m.id=224882
    AND es.operazione IN (8,15)
```

The execution plan doesn't propose any index suggestion..
The record on the affected huges tables are:

- eventi: 12250946
- waypoint_periodi: 650703
- eventi_kml_polygon: 1500040
- kml_polygon: 21870
- kml: 9246

This is the execution plan:
[Execution plan brentozar](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJkTTEIPo)

Who could help me please?

I tried to analize index, tables ecc.. but i didn't find the solution.. I image that there is an index that can help my query

Comment: I see multiple key lookups in that query, implying you don't have covering indexes on your tables `waypoint_periodi` and `eventi`). The index(es) on your tables will help us help you here.

Comment: You suggest that the index sholud be covered?
Yes but the view is irrelevant. I can also remove it

Comment: Are any of these foreignkey fields nullable?

Comment: No, would they make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious...Try to bring this into your query designer(CTRL-SHIFT-Q) and click the columns you want to return and see if it runs.

```
SELECT        *
FROM            (SELECT        TOP (2147483647) *
                          FROM            eventi_kml_polygon AS ekp INNER JOIN
                                                    eventi AS e ON e.id = ekp.id_evento INNER JOIN
                                                    sistema_eventi AS es ON es.evento = e.id_evento INNER JOIN
                                                    waypoint_periodi AS wp ON e.dataora BETWEEN wp.dataora_inizio AND wp.dataora_fine INNER JOIN
                                                    modelli AS m ON m.id = wp.id_modello
                          WHERE        (m.id = 224882) AND (es.operazione IN (8, 15))) AS derivedtbl_1 INNER JOIN
                         kml AS k INNER JOIN
                         kml_polygon AS kp ON k.id = kp.id_kml INNER JOIN
                         waypoint AS w ON w.id_kml = k.id ON derivedtbl_1.id_kml_polygon = kp.id AND derivedtbl_1.id_waypoint = w.id
```

Comment: Thk
I tried to run it with your istruction but the execution time is similar. 
anything else can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I think the biggest problem is the key lookup caused because ix_eventi is not covering.  Try modifying that index to include the columns that are referenced, such as lat, lon, dateora, and so forth.  Of course you will need to determine if this will impede other queries on your server.

Comment: In a test enviroment i copied the db and a tried to remove all indexes in the table "eventi".
Then i tried to re-run the query and magically it is very fast (a few second)
I don't understand.

The main problem is that there indexes serve me for other queries..

Comment: This is the new query plan:

Comment: [plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ry1npchwi)

Comment: The "incriminate" index is "ix_eventi(31_4_7)". After remove this index the query become fast!

Comment: At this point I wonder: why does the sql compiler evaluate the query with the index rather than without it?

Comment: Well, normally I would not suggest this, but if the query runs quickly when using a specific index, you could give it a query hint.  But those can be dangerous if other values are put in the query that would not run well with the forced index.

Comment: I don't prefer tu use a query hint, because as you say it is dangerous (other query can succesfully use it). However, i think the only solution is covering the index..